# Proof on showing function $f \in C^1$ on an open & convex set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is Lipschitz on compact subsets of $U$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is as follows:

> **Given:**
>
> (1) function $f: U \subset \mathbb R^n ==> \mathbb R$
>
> (2) $U$ is open and convex set
>
> (3) $f \in  C^1$ in $U$
>
> **Goal:** Show that $f$ is Lipschitz on any compact subset of $U$

**By now, I have various ideas come to mind, but I can't connect the dots >_<**

**Here are my thoughts so far:**

**(1) Recall definitions:**

**(i)** $f \in C^k$ means all partial derivatives up to (and including) order $k$ exist and continuous.  Here $k = 1$

**(ii)** a set $U$ is convex if for any 2 points $x, y$ in $U$, the segment joining $x$ and $y$ is totally inside $U$

**(iii)** function $f$ is Lipschitz if there is a bound $M$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M |x-y|$

**(2)By a theorem in my book:**

> if function $f \in C^1$ on an open & convex set $U$, then for any 2
>   points $x$ and $y$ in $U$, there is a point $s$ lying on the segment
>   joining $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x) - f(y) = Df(s) * (x - y)$

I firstly have a feeling that I may need this theorem in the proof, but I can't see the connection between my desired bound $M$ with $Df(s)$.  So I tried to think of other ideas and ...

**(3)** It turns out that by all the given information, I think if I can show function $f$ is convex, then I'm done because there is a theorem which said: a convex function on a open, convex set $U$ should be Lipschitz on $U$, thus I think it must also be Lipschitz on any subset of $U$, either that subset is compact or not.

However, how can I prove function $f$ is convex, based on given information?  I have a feeling that I have to use the fact that set $U$ is convex, but then I'm stuck on how to proceed further >_>

*Would someone please help me on this question?
Thank you very much ^_^*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the **Mean Value theorem in several variables**, as you already stated it:

For $x,y\in U$ there exists $s$ which lies on the line segment between $x$ and $y$ ( this line segment is contained in $U$, since it is convex), such that:
$$f(x)-f(y)=\nabla f(s)\cdot (x-y)\Rightarrow\text{( Cauchy-Schwarz )}$$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|\nabla f(s)|\cdot |x-y|$$

Now, take a compact subset $S$ of $U$, and $x,y\in S$. Then take a convex compact set $S'$ such that $S\subset S'\subset U$.This is because we want $s\in S'.$

Now, since $f\in C^1$ , **the first partial derivatives are continuous, and therefore, bounded in the compact set** $S'$. This implies that $|\nabla f(s)|\leq M$

Concluding, for each $x,y\in S$ we have that :
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M\cdot |x-y|$$
which proves that $f$ is Lipschitz in $S$.